# Conditionally update JSON column

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has ID & JSON columns. ID is auto incrementing column. Here are my sample data.

Row 1

```
1  |  {
          "HeaderInfo": 
          {
              "Name": "ABC",
              "Period": "2010",
              "Code": "123"
          }, 
          "HData": 
              [
                 { "ID1": "1", "Value": "$1.00", "Code": "A", "Desc": "asdf" }, 
                 { "ID1": "2", "Value": "$1.00", "Code": "B", "Desc": "pqr" }, 
                 { "ID1": "3", "Value": "$1.00", "Code": "C", "Desc": "xyz" }
              ]
      }
```

Row 2

```
2  | { 
         "HeaderInfo": 
         {
             "Name": "ABC",
             "Period": "2010",
             "Code": "123"
         }, 
         "HData": 
             [
                 { "ID1": "76", "Value": "$1.00", "Code": "X", "Desc": "asdf" },
                 { "ID1": "25", "Value": "$1.00", "Code": "Y", "Desc": "pqr" }, 
                 { "ID1": "52", "Value": "$1.00", "Code": "Z", "Desc": "lmno" }, 
                 { "ID1": "52", "Value": "$1.00", "Code": "B", "Desc": "xyz" }
             ]
     }
```

and it keep goes. Items inside the HData section is infinite. It can be any numbers of items.

On this JSON I need to update the Value = "$2.00" where "Code" is "B". I should be able to do this with 2 scenarios. My parameter inputs are @id=2, @code="B", @value="$2.00". @id sometimes will be null. So,

1. If @id is null then the update statement should go through all records and update the Value="$2.00" for all items inside the HData section which has Code="B".
2. If @id = 2 then the update statement should update only the second row which Id is 2 for the items which Code="b"

Appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? There are loads of resources out there about updating JSON data, which you could attempt to adapt to your circumstances.

Comment: I got some bad news for you, JSON modifying support in SQL Server is pretty weak, the standard JSON_MODIFY function can only update one value per column at a time, hardcoded to a path (although i think SQL Server 2017 supports path expressions).  For #2, you can probably use JSON_MODIFY with a path. for #1 i guess yiou need to slice up and rebuilt the json with new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6GfX_8lc) for an example.

```sql
declare @id bigint = 2
  , @code nvarchar(8) = 'B'
  , @value nvarchar(8) = '$2.00'

update a
set json = JSON_MODIFY(json, '$.HData[' + HData.[key] + '].Value', @value)
from so75416277 a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (json, '$.HData') HData
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (HData.Value, '$')
  WITH (
      ID1 bigint
    , Value nvarchar(8)
    , Code nvarchar(8)
    , [Desc] nvarchar(8)
  ) as HDataItem
WHERE id = @id
AND HDataItem.Code = @Code
```

- The `update` / `set` statement says we want to replace the value of `json` with a new generated value / functions exactly the same as it would in any other context; e.g. `update a set json = 'something' from so75416277 a where a.column = 'some condition'`
- The `JSON_MODIFY` does the manipulation of our json.

  - The first input is the original `json` field's value
  - The second is the path to the value to be updated.
  - The third is the new value
- `'$.HData[' + HData.[key] + '].Value'` says we go from our JSON's root (`$`), find the `HData` field, filter the array of values for the one we're after (i.e. `key` here is the array item's index), then use the `Value` field of this item.
- `key` is a special term; where we don't have a `WITH` block accompanying our `OPENJSON` statement we get back 3 items: `key`, `value` and `type`; key being the identifier, value being the content, and type saying what sort of content that is.
- `CROSS APPLY` allows us to perform logic on a value from a single DB rowto return potentially multiple rows; e.g. like a `join` but against its own contents.
- `OPENJSON (json, '$.HData') HData` says to extract the `HData` field from our `json` column, and return this with the table alias `HData`; as we've not included a `WITH`, this `HData` column has 3 fields; `key`, `value`, and `type`, as mentioned above (this is the same `key` we used in our `JSONMODIFY`).
- The next `OPENJSON` works on `HData.Value`; i.e. the contents of the array item under HData.  Here we take the object from this array (i.e. that's the root from the current context; hence `$`), and use `WITH` to parse it into a specific structure; i.e. ID1, Value, Code, and Desc (brackets around Desc as it's a keyword).  We give this the alias HDataItem.
- Finally we filter for the bit of the data we're interested in; i.e. on `id` to get the row we want to update, then on `HDataItem.Code` so we only update those array items with code `'B'`.

Comment: Thanks. One follow up question. How can I insert a new HData item into Row 1 please? –

Comment: Np. For that, use the `append` operation.  See the `append $.skills` [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#example---basic-operations).  If you still have issues, post what you've tried as a fresh question and the community can assist you further.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below SP.

```
CREATE PROC usp_update_75416277
(
    @id     Int = null, 
    @code   Varchar(15), 
    @value  Varchar(15)
)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLStr Varchar(MAX)=''

    ;WITH   CTE
    AS
    (   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY YourTable.Json ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RowNo,*
        FROM    YourTable 
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(YourTable.Json,'$.HData') 
        WITH (
            ID1     Int         '$.ID1',
            Value   Varchar(20) '$.Value',
            Code    Varchar(20) '$.Code',
            [Desc]  Varchar(20) '$.Desc'
        )   HData 
        WHERE   (@id IS NULL OR ID =@id)
        
    )
    SELECT    @SQLStr=@SQLStr+' UPDATE  YourTable 
                                SET     [JSON]=JSON_MODIFY(YourTable.Json,
                                                            ''$.HData['+CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),RowNo-1)+'].Value'',
                                                            '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@value)+''') '+
                                'WHERE ID ='+CONVERT(Varchar(15),CTE.ID) +' ' 
        
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   Code=@code
        AND (@id IS NULL OR ID =@id)

    EXEC( @SQLStr) 

END
```